# jquery.min.js ineterferring with datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-pagination

I have some code that has a jquery datepicker and also some code for pagination. Now my problem is when I add the following:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js'>
```

My date picker does not work.

If I comment the above my pagination code does not work.
here is my jquery code code:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' />"
puts "<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js'></script>"
puts "<script src='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.0/jquery-ui.js'></script>"
puts "<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js'></script>"

puts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery( '#startdatepicker' ).datepicker();

    });

    </script>
}
puts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery( '#enddatepicker' ).datepicker();

    });
    </script>
}
puts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {

    function Data_Load()
    {
    jQuery("#loading").fadeIn(900,0);
    #jQuery("#loading").html('<img src="bigLoader.gif" />');
    }

    function Hide_Load()
    {
    jQuery("#loading").fadeOut('slow');
    };


    jQuery("#pagination li:first")
    .css({'color' : '#FF0084'}).css({'border' : 'none'});
    Data_Load();
    jQuery("#jcontent").load("nbonbs_log.cgi?page=1", Hide_Load());


    jQuery("#pagination li").click(function(){
    Data_Load();

    jQuery("#pagination li")
    .css({'border' : 'solid #dddddd 1px'})
    .css({'color' : '#0063DC'});

    jQuery(this)
    .css({'color' : '#FF0084'})
    .css({'border' : 'none'});

    var pageNum = this.id;
    jQuery("#jcontent").load("nbonbs_log.cgi?page=" + pageNum, Hide_Load());
    });

    });
    </script>
}
```

Comment: You're including two different versions of jQuery.

Comment: Just include the latest jQuery version ??

Comment: jQuery UI 1.9.0 supports jQuery 1.6+ so no 1.3.x. Remove it and solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes if you include the JQUERY library more than once it causes issues. Maybe try commenting out the first JQUERY include (jquery-1.8.2.js).

Just a guess.

Comment: If i comment  the version out my datepicker still does not work.

Comment: Hmm maybe try a different version of Jquery and hopefully find one that works with both of them. I would try 1.6.